# pass multiple parameters into page.evaluate()

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am passing an additional parameter into the implicit map()  function.

this is found in this part of the code

```
{ s: elementPath.match(RegExp(/=(.*?)]/))[1] }
```

Instead of the Regex i would like to pass an additional parameter state into the outer functions so that the inner function map() could access it

```
let res = await page.evaluate(elementPath => {
  return Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll(elementPath),
    function(cin, index) {
      const result = {
        cinemaState: this.s, 
        cinemaIndex: index,
        cinemaId: cin.getAttribute("data-id"),
        cinemaName: cin.getAttribute("data-name"),
        cinemaURL: cin.getAttribute("data-url")
      };
      return result;
    },
    { s: elementPath.match(RegExp(/=(.*?)]/))[1] } // extracts state from the selector //TODO pass as additional argument 
  );
}, `div[data-state=${state}] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`);
```

I am not sure how the parameter could be cascaded down from the outer functions into the inner most function. Would appreciate any guidance

Comment: Why use `this`? Wouldn't it be easier just to extract what you need from `elementPath` beforehand? (also, regular expression literals are probably preferable over the constructor) If you want to pass additional arguments to `page.evaluate`, just pass them (eg 3rd parameter will correspond to second parameter in callback)

Comment: i managed to change with state as an additional parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass as many as necessary parameters into `page.evaluate` as long as they're serializable:

```
await page.evaluate( (selector, state) => {
    console.log(selector)
    console.log(state)
}, "div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox", state);
```

Comment: changed code works and looks like below
  
 `let res = await page.evaluate(
    (elementPath, state) => {
      return Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(elementPath),
        function(cin, index) {
          let result = {
            cinemaState: this.s,

          };
          return result;
          console.log(result);
        },
        { s: state} 
      );
    },
    `div[data-state=${state}] div.top-select-option a.eccheckbox`,
    state
  );`